# OpenSSL - error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl

I was trying to create a SSL certificate to use with MySQL as like mentioned here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-ssl-certs.html

While verifying the certificates I got the  following error

```
  # openssl verify -CAfile ca-cert.pem server-cert.pem client-cert.pem
    server-cert.pem: C = IN, ST = KERALA, L = COCHIN, O = ABCD, OU = OPERATIONAL, CN = SATHISH, emailAddress = sathish@abcd.com
    error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
    OK
    client-cert.pem: C = IN, ST = KERALA, L = COCHIN, O = ABCD, OU = OPERATIONAL, CN = sathish, emailAddress = sathish@abcd.com
    error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
    OK
```

Could someone help me on generating keys without any errors based on the document in the above link.

Comment: The link to mysql document is dead. I've try to guess what your original link look like. Perhaps it is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-rsa-files.html now.

Comment: (with the solution below) it is practical to use the server's hostname as CN in the server certificate. Also, for ppl that read this while mysql 8 is out, the docs for creating certificates for mysql 8 are clearer (and work with 5x of course) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html#creating-ssl-files-using-openssl-unix-script

Answer (score 189):

I think you missed this part of the instructions:

> Whatever method you use to generate the certificate and key files, the
>   Common Name value used for the server and client certificates/keys
>   must each differ from the Common Name value used for the CA
>   certificate. Otherwise, the certificate and key files will not work
>   for servers compiled using OpenSSL.

When OpenSSL prompts you for the Common Name for each certificate, use different names.

Comment: I had the same issue: after you enter some values for the Distinguished Name you can enter the value for the Common Name.

Comment: I have the same issue when generated ca.pem and client.pem with the same CN, thanks u!

Answer (score 5):

When you use `openssl` command that creates the certificates and keys, it will ask you to fill some fields, and you will come across **`Common Name`** option like following:

```
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:
```

In this case you need to provide a different name each time  and **not** to let it use the default value.

For example:

CA Cert:  app-ca-cert.

Server Cert: app-server-cert.

Client Cert:  app-client-cert.

As the [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html) explained

> Important
>
> Whatever method you use to generate the certificate and key files, the
> Common Name value used for the server and client certificates/keys
> must each differ from the Common Name value used for the CA
> certificate. Otherwise, the certificate and key files do not work for
> servers compiled using OpenSSL.