# Make client send certificate to server during authentication

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, certificate, mutual-authentication

I have set up my client-server communication using OpenSSL and my server is sending it's certificate. Now, I want to make my client send a certificate to the server as well. On my client side, i have the following code:

```
ctx = InitCTX();
LoadCertificates(ctx, "clientCert.pem", "clientCert.pem"); /* load certs */ 
server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
```

and this is my `LoadCertificates` function:

```
void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }
    printf("Certificate attached.\n");
}
```

I have the same `LoadCertificates` function on the server side, and that seems to be working perfectly.

However, my client-side certificate is not getting detected on the server side. Is there anything different I need to do on the client side to send a certificate across?

I made modifications to the client code using the code from here as base: http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html

Answer (score 1):

> ... my client-side certificate is not getting detected on the server side. Is there anything different I need to do on the client side to send a certificate across?

The server needs to call [`SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_add_client_CA.html). It tells the server to send a list of Distinguished Names (DN) which it accepts for client authentication.

The server will need to call [`SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html) (or friends). This is where the server actually trusts the CAs in the list sent to the client.

Finally, the server should call [`SSL_CTX_set_verify`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) and set both `SSL_VERIFY_PEER` and `SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the certificate is sent but was not accepted by the server, that is it could not be verified against the trusted CA at the server. The error message on the server side about `no certificate returned` might be misleading, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951490/3081018.

I would suggest to check with wireshark or `openssl s_server` to see if the certificate is not sent or if it is just not accepted by the peer.