# Golang connect to Postgres using SSL certificate

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, ssl, openssl

First of all, question is languate-agnostic. I'm trying to write a simple application that connects to PostgreSQL using SSL.

1. I created certificates using scripts:

```
# Create CA private key
openssl genrsa -des3 -out root.key 4096
#Remove a passphrase
openssl rsa -in root.key -out root.key

# Create a root Certificate Authority (CA)
openssl \
    req -new -x509 \
    -days 365 \
    -subj "/CN=localhost" \
    -key root.key \
    -out root.crt

# Create server key
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 4096
#Remove a passphrase
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key

# Create a root certificate signing request
openssl \
    req -new \
    -key server.key \
    -subj "/CN=localhost" \
    -text \
    -out server.csr

# Create server certificate
openssl \
    x509 -req \
    -in server.csr \
    -text \
    -days 365 \
    -CA root.crt \
    -CAkey root.key \
    -CAcreateserial \
    -out server.crt
```

2. I created a database using:

**init.sql**

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE TESTING_DATA (
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    UUID UUID UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
    INFO NUMERIC(3, 2)
);

INSERT INTO TESTING_DATA (NAME, INFO)
VALUES
    ('Notebook', 1),
    ('Office supplies', 2),
    ('Pencil', 2),
    ('Office supplies', 1),
    ('Eraser', 1),
    ('Coffee', 1),
    ('Cookies', 2),
    ('Puzzles', 5)
;
```

**postgresql.conf**

```
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = '/etc/postgres/security/root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/postgres/security/server.crt'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/postgres/security/server.key'
password_encryption = scram-sha-256
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
local     all      all                md5
host      all      all  127.0.0.1/32  md5
hostssl   all      all  0.0.0.0/0     cert clientcert=1
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres:12-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_USER=pguser
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpassword
ENV POSTGRES_DB=securitylearning

COPY pg_hba.conf postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/config/
COPY --chown=postgres:postgres root.crt server.crt server.key /etc/postgres/security/
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/config/postgresql.conf", "-c", "hba_file=/etc/postgresql/config/pg_hba.conf"]
```

I launched a container, I ensured that from the container itself I can connect to database and select something from the table.

3. I created a simple program:
   **server.go**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    connection := fmt.Sprint(
        " host=localhost",
        " port=5432",
        " user=pguser",
        " dbname=securitylearning",
        " sslmode=verify-full",
        " sslrootcert=root.crt",
        " sslkey=client.key",
        " sslcert=client.crt",
    )
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connection)
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    row := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM TESTING_DATA")
    fmt.Println(row)
}
```

I tried to:

- place files `root.crt`, `server.crt`, `server.key` next to the compiled binary and add to the connection string in go file `sslrootcert`, `sslcert`, `sslkey` [respectively](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Connection_String_Parameters)
- place same files, but with names `root.crt`, `postgresql.crt`, `postgresql.key` in `~/.postgresql/` directory, because [pq](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/ssl.go#L96) [uses](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/ssl.go#L114) them by default.

For now, it's not working. I randomly get one of those two errors:

> read: connection reset by peer

or

> EOF

Could you please help? What am I missing here? Or could you point me to some resources? Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**
Thanks to suggestion in comments, I created client key and certificate, using

```
# Create client key
openssl genrsa -out client.key 4096
#Remove a passphrase
openssl rsa -in client.key -out client.key

# Create client certificate signing request
openssl \
    req -new \
    -key client.key \
    -subj "/CN=172.17.0.2" \
    -out client.csr

# Create client certificate
openssl \
    x509 -req \
    -in client.csr \
    -CA root.crt \
    -CAkey root.key \
    -CAcreateserial \
    -days 365 \
    -text \
    -out client.crt
```

I'm using 172.17.0.2 in CN, because it's host IP from docker container's perspective.

I've tried both:

- using following keys in connection string from program

```
" sslrootcert=root.crt",
" sslkey=client.key",
" sslcert=client.crt",
```

- copying `root.crt`, `client.key`, `client.srt` to `~/.postgresql/`, trying psql with

```
psql "host=localhost port=5432 user=pguser dbname=securitylearning sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=root.crt sslkey=client.key sslcert=client.crt"
```

or without password.

Both ways still fail to connect. In psql case I get error
`psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.`

Comment: Did you look at your server logfiles? Did you try with just `psql` before trying from a program?

Comment: I tried `psql "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres dbname=securitylearning sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=root.crt"`, got _psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request._
psql version on host (fails) is 12.3, on container (succeeds) is 12.2. Nothing in logs either way.

Comment: You didn't describe the creation of a client certificate, but you have configured it to use clientcert.  (Although that shouldn't lead to this error message, but rather a different one).

Comment: @jjanes Thanks! I updated the question. I didn't think about it. Also, I tried to connect without client certificate - md5 option in pg_hba.conf don't work too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions in comments I managed to solve it.

First of all, as suggested, I stepped back and tried to proceed with smaller steps. Such as, securely connect with `psql` from host.

#### Mistake 1

I forgot to add the following property to **postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) says:

> If the list is empty, the server does not listen on any IP interface at all, in which case only Unix-domain sockets can be used to connect to it.

#### Mistake 2

I fell into a little misconception with certificates and their common names (CN). The following points should be applied to scripts that create certificates. In short:

- CN for CA can be anything as long as it is different from the server's
  CN. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53112619/13164066) for details
- CN for server must be IP/hostname by which we will call server from client (here it's `localhost`. But if the database would be located at
  `cooldatabase.com` <- this would be server's CN)
- CN for client must be username by which we will connect (here, it's
  `pguser`)

When I fixed these two issues - I managed to connect via both psql and go program! Also, the default postgresql.conf is **very** informative!

Comment: I did not find any information at `postgresql.conf` about certificates at all.