# error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed CA certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, debian

I have checked the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726138/openssl-error-18-at-0-depth-lookupself-signed-certificate), and it doesn't seem to be relevant: I try to trust self signed CA certificate, not it's derivative.

I generated a certificate with the following config

```
[req]
prompt                  = no
default_bits            = 2048
distinguished_name      = subject
req_extensions          = req_ext
x509_extensions         = x509_ext
[subject]
commonName              = localhost
[req_ext]
basicConstraints        = critical, CA:true
subjectAltName          = @alt_names
[x509_ext]
basicConstraints        = critical, CA:true
keyUsage                = critical, keyCertSign, cRLSign, digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage        = critical, serverAuth
subjectAltName          = critical, @alt_names
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1  = ASN1:UTF8String:ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate
[alt_names]
DNS.1                   = localhost
DNS.2                   = 127.0.0.1
```

then

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
               -keyout localhost.key \
               -out localhost.crt \
               -config localhost.conf
sudo cp localhost.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/
su -
dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

then I see the certificate is installed

```
root@debian:~# ls -la /etc/ssl/certs | grep localhost
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 Jul 17 11:07 ce275665.0 -> localhost.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     46 Jul 17 15:46 localhost.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localhost.crt
```

However, when I try to validate it, it still fails

```
openssl verify localhost.crt
CN = localhost
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
error localhost.crt: verification failed
sudo openssl verify /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.pem 
CN = localhost
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
error /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.pem: verification failed
```

Debian 12. This certificate config worked perfectly in Fedora, I use it for net core local development using HTTPS.